# Get yarn container log directory in mapper/reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Is there an API to get the yarn log directory location in my mapper/reducer method implementation? So for example if I have the following config

```
yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=/mnt/yarn/log
```

I want to access the subfolder for the container log that's written to this directory e.g.,

```
/mnt/yarn/log/application_1479833596065_1010/container_e06_1479833596065_1010_01_000003
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that container log dir is passed to the JVM by the container executor so I can just read that value (-Dyarn.app.container.log.dir). This works for my purpose.